# Multithreading with a for loop in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, for-loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  MultithreadThing myThing = new MultithreadThing();
  myThing.start();
}
```

Why does a for loop result in multithreading? Wouldn't the process be something like this?:

- New thread object is created.
- The thread starts, runs, then finishes
- The loop iterates

Comment: `myThing.start();` only does *starts* and *runs* (and it returns immediately); for finishes you need `myThing.join()`

Comment: This is a very valid question, and the answer is simply that `Thread.start` is "magic". It has a custom semantic [specified by the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html). You would not be able to implement this behavior in plain Java without specific support from the JLS / JVMS.

Comment: previous comments are only true if `MultithreadThing`  is a subclass of `Thread` (or similar inside its `start()`, e.g. `Exceutor`)- we can only guess that - usually it is better to include a [mre]

Comment: 'MultithreadThing' is a subclass of Thread, so the "magic" start method applies here. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: That information is (still) missing in the question! Then see [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#start()) of `start()`: "*Schedules this thread to begin execution. The thread will execute independently of the current thread.*"

Comment: A for-loop in general doesn't result in multi-threading, this specific for-loop may result in multi-threading, assuming `MultithreadThing` is a `Thread`, or if `start()` otherwise creates and starts a `Thread`, or submits something to an executor.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `MultithreadThing` extends `Thread` as follows,

```
class MultithreadThing extends Thread {
    int number;
    public MultithreadThing (int i) {
        number = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Your Code
        System.out.println("Thread number: " + number);
    }
}
```

In your the given code snippet, a for loop is used to create and start multiple instances of a `MultithreadThing` object. Each time the loop iterates, a new instance of `MultithreadThing` is created, and its `start()` method is called, which typically starts a new thread of execution.

1. Inside the loop body, a new instance of `MultithreadThing` is created using the `new` keyword. This creates a new object in memory.
2. The `start()` method of the `MultithreadThing` object is called. Assuming the `start()` method is implemented to start a new thread as mentioned above, a new thread of execution is created and begins running concurrently with the main thread.
3. The loop variable `i` is incremented.

the loop spawns multiple threads in parallel, and each thread will execute independently and concurrently with the main thread and other threads. The loop does not pause or wait for any thread to finish before proceeding to the next iteration.

If you want to wait for each task to complete before incrementing `i` and moving on to the next iteration of the loop, you can use something like [join()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) method on each thread. The `join()` method blocks the execution of the calling thread until the thread it is called on completes.